# How to solve OverflowError when generating same random numbers between R and Python using SyncRNG

Tags: python, r, random

I am trying to reproduce R codes in Python and I have to generate same random numbers in both languages. I know that using the same seed is not enough to get same random numbers and reading one of the answers on this platform regarding this topic I have discovered that there exists: [SyncRNG](https://gertjanvandenburg.com/blog/syncrng/) library, which generates same random numbers between R and Python. Everything looks fine as long as I have discovered that on Python 3.7.3 I can generate via SyncRNG just one number because as soon as you iterate the procedure, for instance, with a for loop you get this error:

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.

As I was mentioning:

```
>>> from SyncRNG import SyncRNG
>>> s = SyncRNG(seed=123)
>>> r = s.rand()
>>> r
0.016173338983207965
```

and as we can see it works. The method ".rand()" generates random numbers between zero and one.
But if I try to iterate:

```
>>> from SyncRNG import SyncRNG
>>> s = SyncRNG(seed=123)
>>> b = []
>>> for i in range(5):
        temp = s.rand()
        b.append(temp)
```

and I get this:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 2, in <module>
    temp = s.rand()
  File "C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\SyncRNG\__init__.py", line 27, in rand
    return self.randi() * 2.3283064365387e-10
  File "C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\SyncRNG\__init__.py", line 22, in randi
    tmp = syncrng.rand(self.state)
SystemError: <built-in function rand> returned a result with an error set
```

So, I humbly ask if someone is able to solve this problem. If I lost old answers about this topic I'm sorry, please link them in the answer section.
Thank you!

Comment: This code works for me, without the `OverflowError`.  Can you show the stack trace?  Curious if the exception is thrown from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have add the entire output! I hope I have uploaded what you meant.

Comment: are you using 32-bit python?  SyncRNG's `randi()` function may return integers larger than signed 32-bit.

Comment: I am using 64-bit Python right now

Comment: This overflow error has now been fixed: https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/SyncRNG/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a workaround.  The overflow bug is not reproducible on my system.  The workaround:

```
from SyncRNG import SyncRNG
s = SyncRNG(seed=123)
ct = 0
b = []
while ct < 5:
    try:
        temp = s.rand()
        b.append(temp)
        ct += 1
    except OverflowError:
        pass
```

Performance will be compromised due to the try/except on each loop.

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the same error but i have understand what you mean, anyway thank you again for your help!